# Attendance report print in HTML table format

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to print shift in horizontally and name/id in vertically. I have an attendance table like this =>>.
attendance table:
[image: attendance table]

I want to print `shift` value in this table format html table structure:
[image: html table structure]

```
    <?php
    $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("n"),date("Y"));
    $totdate = $d;
    $month = date("F");
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_content">';
    echo "<thead>";
    
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Sl/No</th>";
            echo "<th>Emp.ID</th>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            for ($i=1; $i <= $totdate; $i++) { 
                
                echo "<th>".$i."</th>";
                
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
$qry = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE `month` = '$month'";

$cnt=1;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
foreach ($query as $q) {
    $sid = $q['empid'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$cnt++ ."</td>";
        $st_name_id = "SELECT `emp_id`, `name` FROM `emp` WHERE `id`='$sid'";
        $re = mysqli_query($conn, $st_name_id);
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
            echo "<td>".$result['emp_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
        }
            for ($i=1; $i <= $totdate ; $i++) { 
                $qry2 = "SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE `empid`='$sid' AND `month`='$month' AND `date`='$i'";
                $re2 = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);
                echo "<td>";
                foreach ($re2 as $value => $q) {
                    $dt = $q['date'];
                    $s = $q['shift'];
                    if ($i == $dt) {
                        echo $s;
                        echo "</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td>x</td>";
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What does your code currently do and what isn't working?

Comment: @NigelRen when i take attendance of back date table row count increase and shift value are all over the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$qry ="SELECT * FROM emp";`

Answer (score 1):

HI guys here is the answer. Thank you for support

```
    <?php
    $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("n"),date("Y"));
    $totdate = $d;
    $month = date("F");
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_content">';
    echo "<thead>";
    
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Sl/No</th>";
            echo "<th>Emp.ID</th>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            for ($i=1; $i <= $totdate; $i++) { 
                
                echo "<th>".$i."</th>";
                
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
// $qry = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE `month` = '$month'";
$qry ="SELECT * FROM `emp`";

$cnt=1;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
foreach ($query as $q) {
    $sid = $q['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$cnt++ ."</td>";
        $st_name_id = "SELECT `emp_id`, `name` FROM `emp` WHERE `id`='$sid'";
        $re = mysqli_query($conn, $st_name_id);
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
            echo "<td>".$result['emp_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
        }
            for ($i=1; $i <= $totdate ; $i++) { 
                $ii = sprintf("%02d", $i);
                $qry2 = "SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE `empid`='$sid' AND `month`='$month' AND `date`='$ii'";
                $re2 = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);
                echo "<td>";
                foreach ($re2 as $q) {
                    $dt = $q['date'];
                    $s = $q['shift'];
                    if ($dt == $ii) {
                        echo $s;
                        echo "</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "x</td>";
                    }
                }
                // echo sprintf("%02d", $i) ."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[as accepted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUFM.png)